# Rock Paper Scissors grouping optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization

just trying to find a good algorithm to find an optimal solution using typical RPS rules. I haven't started programming the problem yet.

Given two ordered arrays that contain N elements each, optimize the number of wins by reordering the first array.

For example:

```
a[0] = rock     
a[1] = paper
a[2] = paper
a[3] = rock

b[0] = paper
b[1] = rock
b[2] = scissors
b[3] = rock

// currently
a[0] vs b[0] = -1 // (rock losses to paper)
a[1] vs b[1] = +1 // (paper beats rock)
a[2] vs b[2] = -1 // (paper losses to scissors)
a[3] vs b[3] = 0 // (rock ties to rock)
```

An optimal order that should be returned is { 1, 0, 3, 2 }

```
paper ties paper
rock ties rock
rock beats scissors
paper beats rock
```

The question is, how do I arrive to this result? A few constraints.

Ties are more preferable than having a win and loss offsetting each other. This is probably achieved by weighing a loss more than a win. i.e.

```
a[0] = rock
a[1] = paper
b[0] = paper
b[1] = rock

{0, 1} vs b[..] = -1, +.95 = -.05
{1, 0} vs b[..] = 0, 0 = 0 // preferred order
```

Also, a win at the bottom of the array is preferred.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Each RPS match is independent of each other, so I see no other solution than checking each combination.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm, an implementation (please specify language), or both?

Comment: I'm coding in lua right now. That said, I'm just looking for an algorithm that I can implement.

Answer (score 3):

For small arrays, you could solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem.

For large arrays, note that you can describe any solution exactly by giving the entries in a 3x3 array of counts, where A[i,j] gives the number of times player A said (0 => rock, 1 => paper, 2 => scissors) and B said (0 => rock, 1=> paper, 2=> scissors). So you want to fill in this array to maximise the sum of the cells that amount to a win for A, subject to constraints on the sums down columns which amount to the number of times B said rock, paper, and scissors in its array and ditto along rows for A - the result from this tell you enough to fill in A's array given B's.

You could certainly solve this with Integer Linear Programming. I suspect that the problem is always at a corner and if you solve it with Linear Programming just constraining every entry to be >= 0 you will get an integer answer out, but I haven't formally proved this.